# Downloading documents of type .docx and JPG using REST API

Tags: rest

I am using REST API to fetch the document of type .txt,.docx and JPG, Request header Accept:application/octet-stream, am able to download documents of type .txt but for documents of type .docx and JPG the response message is corrupted and unable to open the documents. Is there any alternate option of downloading documents of type .docx and JPG using REST API

Comment: post some code samples where it shows your problem

Answer (score 1):

Mime type for JPEG - `image/jpeg`.

Mime type for DOCX - `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

A complete list of mime types is available in this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Even after setting the MIME type the response message returned is like this:

Comment: PK␈!ß­úœG␈[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´•ËNÃ0E÷HüCä-J\X „š²€²„J±v�Ic?äq_Ï8-QA))¯M¤Ä¹÷�3“áÍZ×É<*krvž XFÚB™yÎž§÷éK0␈SˆÚÈÙ�ÝŒNO†Ó�LHm0gU␈îšs”h�™u`h¥´^‹@·~Î��¯büb0

Comment: I tried decoding using base 64 util but didn't work.. is it any encoded message format?